# How can I a pivoted procedure be called as a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that generates the pivot below (see output) based on parameters passed to it.

I want to be able to insert columns in between the years as I show in expected output that will add 100 to the pivoted values in this new column.

Is there a way to call a pivot proc as a query so that I can add those calculations via select query? Or is there an easier way?

```
create table t1
(
    date int,
    unita int,
    unitb int,
    unitc int
)

insert into t1 values (2010, 335, 52, 540)
insert into t1 values (2011, 384, 70, 556)
insert into t1 values (2012, 145, 54, 345)


select *
from 
(
    select date, value, unit
    from 
    (
        select *
        from t1
    ) x
    unpivot ([value] for unit in ([unita], [unitb], [unitc])) u
) a
pivot
(
    sum(value)
    for date in ([2010], [2011], [2012])
) p
```

OUTPUT:

```
unit    2010 2011 2012
----------------------
unita   335  384  145
unitb   52   70   54
unitc   540  556  345
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
unit    2010 2010a 2011 2011a  2012
-----------------------------------
unita   335  435   384  485    145
unitb   52   150   70   170    54
unitc   540  640   556  656    345
```

Comment: What determines how many columns you need to add?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's actually an 'easy' way to add columns to result of a pivot. You can't get away without a dynamic sql in that case. So, here's 
one of possible solutions. I've placed some explanations in comments.

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE ([date] varchar(4))
DECLARE @pivotColumns varchar(500)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

-- First, you need to construct list of values you need to pivot - `[2010], [2010a], [2011], [2011a], [2012]`.
SET @pivotColumns = ''

INSERT INTO @dates
SELECT DISTINCT [date] FROM t1

SELECT
    @pivotColumns = @pivotColumns + '[' + CAST([date] AS varchar(4)) + ']' +
        CASE
            WHEN [date] < (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM @dates) THEN + ',[' + CAST([date] AS varchar(4)) + 'a]'
            ELSE ''
        END + ','
FROM @dates ORDER BY [date]

SET @pivotColumns = LEFT(@pivotColumns, LEN(@pivotColumns) - 1)

-- Second - in the innermost query you need all the data for these columns in corresponding rows before unpivot.
-- So we union main query with itself appending 'a' to 'date' values and 
-- incrementing values in unita, unitb, unitc columns by 100 for each row 
-- except for rows with the maximum 'date' value.
-- Third - we use our @pivotColumns variable for pivot columns list. That's what
-- this dynamic query is here for.

SET @query = 
'select *
from 
(
    select [date], value, unit
    from 
    (
        select CAST(date AS varchar(5)) AS [date], unita, unitb, unitc from t1
        union all
        select CAST(date AS varchar(5)) + ''a'', unita + 100, unitb + 100, unitc + 100 from t1
        WHERE [date] < (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM t1)
    ) x
    unpivot ([value] for unit in ([unita], [unitb], [unitc])) u
) a
pivot
(
    sum(value)
    for date in (' + @pivotColumns + ')
) p
'
-- Execute the query.
exec sp_executesql @query
```